# Where is my logcat ? can I know my logcat storage path when thre is no stdout in cmd shell?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I'm trying to filter logcat my package only but as a result I get:

```
C:\Users\User>adb shell logcat -s my.package.name
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
```

So, is it possible to know where android is storing the output if it's not visible on stdout?

Comment: `logcat` filters by `tag` not by package name

Comment: is it possible to filter by package name?

Comment: the `logcat` record does not contain the *package name* field. What is your problem with using a unique string for the tag and then filtering by it?